# How to deploy a Quarkus application on openshift with rolling strategy

Tags: quarkus

How to deploy a quarkus application to a openshift namespace using the rolling deployment strategy?
In my case always the the previous pod will be tear down first.

I would expect some property to define the used deployment strategy.

Currently I use maven to deploy the application

```
mvn clean package -Dquarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true -Dquarkus.openshift.namespace=my_target_namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property in quarkus-kubernetes that allows this: `quarkus.kubernetes.strategy`. Allowed values are `none, recreate, rolling-update`.

Here is the official documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes#quarkus-kubernetes-kubernetes-config_quarkus.kubernetes.strategy

It is important to notice this was added in versión 3 (currently 3.3). I could not verify it myself cause I am using still quarkus-bom 2.13 but I hope it helps someone else.